# Proof of the formula of redundancy bits in Hamming code for single error correction problem

Tags: network, network-theory

1. **m** ---> number of *data bits* of a frame
2. **r** ---> number of *redundancy bits*
3. **n=m+r** ----> lenght of a codeword(data + redundancy bits)

Imagine that we want to design a code with *m* message bits and *r* check bits that will allow all single errors to be corrected.

In the proof of the formula for calculating the number of redundant bits *(m + r + 1) ≤ 2^r*

I've understood the following statement:

> Each of the 2^m legal messages has
> n illegal codewords at a distance(Hamming distance) of 1 from it.These are formed by systematically
> inverting each of the n bits in the n-bit codeword formed from it.

But I'm currently stuck on the following statement:

> *Thus*, each of
> the 2^m legal messages requires n + 1 bit patterns dedicated to it.

In particularly I don't understand that *thus* in the second statement. Why is the second statement  a *consequence* of the first one?

[image]

Tanenbaum's proof:

[image]

Comment: Please link to the source of the quotes so we can see them in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally understood why the above second statement is a consequence of the first one.

Every one of the four messages in the above is associated with a legal codeword plus *n* illegal ones.

- *Legal codewords* : made up by an even number of one
- *Illegal codewords* : made up by an odd number of one

For example the first message *00* has 4 codewords associated with it of whom
3 of them are illegal
( each one obtained by inverting each single bit of the legal codeword *000* associated with the first message *00*  ):

1. *001*
2. *010*
3. *100*

plus the legal one :

4. *000*

Therefore the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

> Thus, each of the 2^m legal messages requires n + 1 bit patterns dedicated to it.

*m* data bits allow for 2^*m* different messages. These are reproduced using *m+r* channel bits, so that the Hamming distance between the legal channel messages allow you to reproduce (single) bit errors and correct them.